# Decode a Javascript hex literal in C#

Tags: c#, character-encoding

I have the following string:

```
string s = @"a=q\x26T=1";
```

I want to unescape this to:

```
"a=q&T=1"
```

How do I do this is C# other than just replacing the characters? There are various other escaped characters, so I'm not sure what encoding to use.

Comment: HtmlDecode does not decode \xXX formatted values. The string I indicated appears to be something specific to javascript and javascript can decode it. My doe though needs to be in C#.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
var decodedString = Regex.Unescape(@"source=s_q\x26hl=en");
```

but this works even better:

```
  var regex = new Regex(@"\\x([a-fA-F0-9]{2})");
  json = regex.Replace(json, match => char.ConvertFromUtf32(Int32.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)));
```